# Angular2 OpenID Connect token validation getting failed

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, active-directory, openid-connect

I have downloaded the sample from https://github.com/ITUnity/dev/tree/master/OpenIDConnect and tried to log in to Microsoft. It went well like Microsoft returned token to the redirected URL but at last, it threw errors in the console like 'token validation failed', 'session validation failed'. What are the things I have to do in order to make this sample work?

**Edited:**
It worked when I have changed the certificate which downloaded from my active directory or get from the URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml. Also, I have changed the XML tags in the code to find the X509 Certificate in the XML

Comment: Now when I try to login for the Azure B2C Active Directory using Custom Signin Policy ,it gets authenticated and returning token in the URL. But when I try validate it using jsrsassign js it is saying that JWT signature is invalid. What Should I do now?

Comment: Thanks in Advance!